# Wrong total height of ListView when TextView hasn't got single line

Tags: android, listview

I have got a small issue in my code... The problem is that I need to add height of each `ListView` item (cause I have got it in `ScrollView` and I don't want to have got double scroll places...).

This is my code which allows me to do that:

```
public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        //do nothing return null
        return;
    }
    //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        totalHeight += listItem.getPaddingTop() + listItem.getPaddingBottom();
    }
    //setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    // print height of adapter on log
    Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
}
```

And I call this function here:

```
final ReceivedAttachementsListArrayAdapter adapter = new ReceivedAttachementsListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), attachements);
mReceivedAttachementsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
ViewHelper.getListViewSize(mReceivedAttachementsListView);
```

When my `TextView` is 1 line length or 3 line length, `totalHeight` of `ListView` items still gives me the same result.

Any idea to improve my method?

Comment: "double scroll places" Can you explain what do you mean by this? A photo may help

Comment: I mean that when I don't set height of `ListView` it show only one item and I must scroll to get next items...

Comment: @Selvin I read this and I know (from posts) but in my specifications it is said I must use `ListView` so I don't really have a choice...